Why the col-auto with red border taking extra height than it's available content?
I have used bootstrap 5 version for this code. When you check this in full screen width the col-auto with the red border takes extra space than it's available content. The content space inside is marked with yellow border. I wonder what causing the this space break. Can some one please help?


html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.search-field .form-control {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.search-field .form-control-search {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 2.375rem;
  height: 2.375rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row flex-column h-100">
        <div class="col-auto py-2 border border-danger bg-light-subtle">
            <div class="row g-0 align-items-center border border-warning">
                    <div class="col-auto pe-2">
                        <div class="rounded bg-dark text-light p-1 lh-1">
                            <i class="bi bi-person-check align-middle lh-1"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 align-self-end">
                        <h6 class="fw-bold text-truncate pt-1">Assigned</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-lg-4 ms-auto">
                        <form class="pr-2">
                            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected="">Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <hidden id=""></hidden>
                        <button id="" class="btn btn-outline-primary border-0 ms-2">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="align-middle" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="">
                                    <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14m0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16"></path>
                                    <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4"></path>
                                </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto form-group mb-0 search-field position-relative ps-2">
                        <span class="fa fa-search form-control-search"></span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control text-muted search" id="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto ps-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary border-0">
                            <i class="bi bi-grid"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                                
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col position-relative bg-light" style="min-height: 0;">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>




Please clarify your question. takes extra space than it's available content - what does that even mean?

@MrUpsidown run the snippet on full screen like he said and you will see the extra space

@MrUpsidown as you can see the col-auto with red border need to take the height of the yellow border. But currently it is taking more height. I think col-auto should take only the height of content inside it.

@TemaniAfif I don't see extra space. Extra space between what and what? extra space than it is available content doesn't mean much to me.

@MrUpsidown well, it's clear for me and I do see that space.

@TemaniAfif I asked for clarification. The col-auto element's height is bigger than its content height would probably have been much clearer. Let me know if it's wrong to ask for clarification when a question sounds unclear.

@MrUpsidown and we were both trying to clarify that space. Who said you were wrong? If it was the case I won't even bother commenting.

It appears to be somehow related to that search input field - as soon as I set that to display: none, the column height shrinks to the "expected" one. Not sure why it causes this effect yet though.

Removing col-lg-4 from the 3rd column also seems to fix the issue. Not sure why.

Why do you need that extra column with bg-light? Tbh. your code is a bit of a mess and we don't know exactly what the expected result should be. Do you need the elements to be 100% height (where h-100 was used)? I would think there might be easier ways to achieve the same results but I am unsure what the result should be. Maybe share an illustration of what you need for the various devices sizes.

@MrUpsidown please check this link

EDIT
I didn't read the question enough. The problem seems to be that col-auto adds the flex shorthand property
flex: 0 0 auto;

the last value(auto) is the flex-basis
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis
In your code you have 2 columns with direction column, since the first column has flex-basis f "auto" and the second "0", the col-auto makes the first one get the extra space out of the parent row(h-100).
This side effect is only happening on desktop viewports
OLD ANSWER
py-2 next to col-auto is causing this as it is an inner padding on the outter div

<div class="col-auto py-2 border border-danger bg-light-subtle">


remove py-2

Did you read the question (and the clarification provided by OP in the comments section)? This does not provide a solution to the described issue.

you are right, I didn't read the question right
